# Variable assignment issue in multiline macro in GNU Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I understand that this is a simple question but i am unable to find the reason/solution. I have defined a simple shell function in Makefile that is doing as follows,

```
define my_function
    my_var="Hello";
    echo $(my_var);
    echo Recvd arg = $(1);
endef
```

Please note that this is defined inside a makefile and I am using in one of my rule,

```
 $(obj_dir)/%.o: $(src_base)/%.cpp 
 $(q)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ 
 $(call my_function, $@)
```

But the local variable my_var never gets assigned. I have tried many things using eval, set and export but nothing seems to be assigning value to variable in the function. And echo $(my_var) will just print nothing. This works fine in shell script but when used in Makefile, it causes this issue.

Please help me sort this out. Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't given enough information.  How exactly are you using the `$(call my_function...)`?  Is it inside a recipe?  Or not?  Please provide the full context where you use the call function.

Comment: call is inside one of my build rule. Such that,

    $(obj_dir)/%.o: $(src_base)/%.cpp
    $(q)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@
    $(call my_function, $@)

 I have verified that function is getting called correctly but the operation inside i.e. variable assignment is not working.

Comment: description of question updated. please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make will invoke every logical line of a recipe in a separate shell.  So for something like:

```
foo:
        echo line1
        echo line2
```

this starts two different shells, one to run the first echo and another to run the second (in reality make has some performance enhancements so that it avoids starting a shell if the command is "simple enough", but the behavior is the same either way).

So if you write a variable in one line then use it in another line, the value will be lost when the shell exits:

```
foo:
        foo=bar
        echo $$foo
```

prints nothing.  In order to use multiple physical lines but a single logical line you must end each physical line with a backslash/newline combination: make will collect them and send them to a single shell:

```
foo:
        foo=bar; \
        echo $$foo
```

will print "bar".

This holds true even within multi-line variable assignments.  Also, you must use `$$` (as I do above) when you want to refer to a *shell* variable.  Using a single `$` will refer to the *make* variable by that name.  And the shell variable referencing doesn't support parentheses (but you can use curly braces if you want).  So you must write:

```
define my_function
    my_var="Hello"; \
    echo $$my_var; \
    echo Recvd arg = $(1);
endef
```

Comment: tip: If your macro only uses _shell_ variables (and no _make_ variables), you can usefully use the `$(value …)` macro to save having to double every `$`. [Similarly, if you pass a load of stuff to `$(eval …)`.]

Answer (score 0):

I have nothing to add to MadScientist's answer but this: If you don't mind slightly longer lines, you can also place several shell commands on one line separated by semicolons:

```
define my_function
    my_var="Hello"; echo $$my_var; echo Recvd arg = $(1)
endef
```