# Makefile recipe not working

Tags: bash, makefile

I wrote a recipe to check if a dir excists. But i think that normal BASH syntax cannot be applied because i keep on running into an error.
The recipe i wrote is:

```
dircheck:
    if [ ! -d "$/data/DIV5/SASC/project-064-ronald-svdz/analysis/runs/peak_calls_ctrls" ];        then
        echo Directory does not excists peak_calls_ctrll will be created.
        mkdir /data/DIV5/SASC/project-064-ronald-svdz/analysis/runs/peak_calls_ctrls
    else
        echo Directory already excists continuing the analysis!
    fi
```

The error i ran into: `run_MACS.mk:12: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

i know its the syntax but i dont know what to change.

Comment: See [this answer][1] for a discussion of writing rules containing multiple lines.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544784/variable-assignment-issue-in-multiline-macro-in-gnu-makefile/22545855#22545855

Comment: MadScientist is of course 100% right.  [From the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Splitting-Recipe-Lines).  I'm voting to mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `\`'s at the end of your lines to concatenate them into a single line.  (make invokes a new shell for each line in a recipe, so your `if[...]` is considered as a separate shell command from the `else`, etc.