# Makefile function with multiple statements

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

[HEADS UP] : There are some similar questions that are already present here on stackoverflow but they seem to not completely resolve my issue. Therefore, I am posting this question.
I am trying to write a makefile function that should set a value to a variable that is passed as argument to the function.
So, I am calling this function as -

```
RESULT :=
$(eval $(call myfunction,RESULT,value,res1,res2))
```

here 'res1' and 'res2' are two possible resulting values for RESULT and the argument 'value' will be used for some test condition.

Following is my attempt of the definition of myfunction. But it seems that it is not working.

```
define myfunction
TEST1 := $(shell test `mybinary` -ge 5 && printf "TEST")
TEST2 := $(findstring $(2),$(SOME_SHELL_ENV))
$(info "$(TEST1)")
$(info "$(TEST2)")

ifneq "$$(or $(TEST1),$(TEST2)" ""
    LOCAL_RESULT := true
else
    LOCAL_RESULT := false
endif

ifeq($(LOCAL_RESULT),true)
    $(1) = $(3)
else
    $(1) = $(4)
endif
endef
```

To me it appears that the local variables TEST1 and TEST2 are not even getting set.
Can somebody tell me why my function is not working correctly and what changes do I have to make to resolve the issues?

Comment: GNU make can be extended with Guile or with plugins. Consider using them. And use  [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) to debug your `Makefile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [eval manual page](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html#Eval-Function):

> The `eval` function is very special: *[...]* The argument to the `eval` function is expanded, then the results of that expansion are parsed as makefile syntax.
>
> It’s important to realize that the `eval` argument is expanded ***twice***; first by the `eval` function, then the results of that expansion are expanded again when they are parsed as makefile syntax. This means you may need to provide extra levels of escaping for “$” characters when using `eval`.

This happens after `$(call)` arguments are substituted, so `$1` etc are already expanded by the time `$(eval)` is called, and need not to be `$`-escaped.

To make variables expand during the last (parsing) stage of `$(eval)`, escape `$`s of non-numeric variables by doubling them.

```
define myfunction
TEST1 := $$(shell test `echo 6` -ge 5 && printf "TEST")
TEST2 := $$(findstring $(2),$$(PATH))
$$(info "$$(TEST1)")
$$(info "$$(TEST2)")

ifneq "$$(or $$(TEST1),$$(TEST2))" ""
    LOCAL_RESULT := true
else
    LOCAL_RESULT := false
endif

ifeq ($$(LOCAL_RESULT), true)
    $(1) = $(3)
else
    $(1) = $(4)
endif
endef

$(eval $(call myfunction,RESULT,value,res1,res2))
test:
    echo "$(LOCAL_RESULT)"
```

Plus, you had a missing closing brace in `$(or)`.

It's not clear if `res1` and `res2` are variable names or values; depending on this, the last two assignments need or need not to look like `$(1) := $($(4))`.

Try to always use eager assignments: `:=`, for fewer surprises from lazy variable expansion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This seems to work. I am still confused why $$ is required everywhere and also why is it not required for $(2),$(3).

Comment: Also, res1 and res2 are values (I had already mentioned that in question) . Can you explain $($(4)) ? Is it different from $$(4)?

Comment: Updated the answer to answer first comment. For the second comment, $($(4)) is quite intuitive: it's "the value of the variable named by argument 4 of `call`". `eval` escaping rules still apply.

Comment: Another follow-up question : MadScientist's answer to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544784/variable-assignment-issue-in-multiline-macro-in-gnu-makefile states that "Make will invoke every logical line of a recipe in a separate shell" , then how I does this solution able to maintain values of TEST1,TEST2,LOCAL_RESULT throughout the function?

Comment: They are make variables, not shell variables.